# Show buttons dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, button, datatable, show

I'm making an application (windows form) where I have different buttons. My objective is to show different buttons depending on the value of a variable. For example, if the value of the variable is 10, it will show the first 10 buttons.

So far, my code is:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id_produto, designacao FROM 
produtos ORDER BY id_categoria ASC;", mConn);
MySqlDataAdapter dacom = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
mConn.Open();
dacom.Fill(dtprodutos);
numprodutos = dtprodutos.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 1; i <= numprodutos; i++)
{
    bprod[i].Show();
}
```

My buttons are called bprod1, bprod2, bprod3, etc.
What I'm doing is to get the "id_produto" and "designacao" from "produtos" and put them into a DataTable.
Then I create a variable with the number of rows of "dtprodutos".
Finally i create a loop to show the buttons.

My problem is that Visual Studio does not allow me to do "bprod[i].Show();" because he thinks it is a variable that was not created.

I appreciate any suggestions and help.

Comment: I have the same problem as your compiler: I do not know what `bprod` is supposed to be. Where is it defined?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to say...my buttons are called bprod1, bprod2, bprod3, etc, til 25. This is a windows form application.

Comment: I would assume that `bprod` would go from `0` to `numprodutos - 1`. So you'd need to have: `for (int i = 0; i < numprodutos; i++)` (notice 2 changes there.) Is that it?

Comment: If your first button is called `bprod1` for example, what makes you think that you can access it like `bprod[1]`?

Comment: Thanks @ispiro, my problem is inside the loop, because the code inside it doesn't work, and I don't know to to show the buttons inside the loop. I don't know if I'm making myself clear, anything else you want to know ask me.

Comment: @Pikoh that's exactly my problem, because I know I can't access it like this, but it was only an experiment.

Comment: There are many duplicates to this question. You need either to create an [array or List of buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037716/create-array-collection-of-buttons-from-existing-buttons), or access the `Controls` collection of your form, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365228/winforms-button-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WinForms Button Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365228/winforms-button-array)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put all your buttons in a typed list. Declare it on the scope of form (above form constructor, for an example). Then, add all buttons to your list, after `InitializeComponent` (or in `Form_Load`).

```
List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    buttonList.Add(bprod1);
    buttonList.Add(bprod2);
    //etc
}
```

finally, when you execute your query and get number (`numprodutos`), show that many elements (buttons, in fact) from your list

```
numprodutos = dtprodutos.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 1; i <= numprodutos; i++)
{
    buttonList[i].Show();
}
```

or, using linq

```
buttonList.Take(numprodutos).ToList().ForEach(btn => btn.Show());
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It works! You cannot imagine how much time I spent on this. Thanks one more time!

Comment: It wasn't me...I can't even vote pubicly...and your answer helped me!

Comment: @MiniKing17-Tiago, don't worry, I'm not accusing anyone. It would be nice, from the person who downvoted, do explain why downvote... so I can learn and skip mistake or wrong practice next time.

Comment: The person who downvoted you, downvoted my question too, I think.